# How to disable console.trace tree in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, console

I remember that I've somewhere in chrome console options, enabled trace console (if i correctly remember).

Now, i notice that in console i have huge unfolded logs like:
[image]

that junk info takes my whole window, and it's annoying. How can I remove them? (btw, i think that manual recreation of `console.log()=null` is not solution).

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? It's incredibly annoying!

Comment: Almost 6 years and they still did not changed this time costing annoying little "feature"

Answer (score 11):

You can filter specific messages (e.g. hide) by right click on the little arrow in front of, in your example, console.trace.
the first option in the menu will be to hide all messages from JQMIRATE. After selecting this option you will not see anymore these pesty messages.

Answer (score 0):

there seems no quick-fix answer here, so, in some cases (not recommended, but for development), in the top of the html, you might try:

```
console.trace = null;  //or window.console.trace=null;
```